# Jenkins builds are being triggered without a trigger

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I inherited a project set up to use Jenkins. I set the trigger to poll SCM every 5 minutes and disabled the pre-existing build remotely trigger. So now the only trigger set for Jenkins is to poll SCM every 5 minutes. However jenkins is building the project everytime the project repo is updated and NOT on polling. The polling log specifically says that it won't build (due to the author of the commit being in the excluded list) but the project builds anyway, unrelated to the polling. There are no other triggers set.

I didn't find any scripts anywhere that could explain this behaviour.

Comment: What is the SCM tool being used here?

Comment: Maybe you have hook in your SCM that triggers this job after update?